# A Generic error occured in GDI+ on Server Machine

Tags: c#, .net, image, visual-studio-2010, gdi

I Tried many solutions to remove Generic error Occured in GDI + but nothing is working for me , I am posting Codes that i had used.This error occured in server machine
Images bytes are stored successfully in Database but doesnt retrieve on PictureBox.

1st Method :
**ODetail.InsuranceCardImages** Contains **Bytes** of Images From Database.
***pcinsurance*** is my PictureBox

```
                    System.Byte[] imagefront = (byte[])oDetail.InsuranceCardImage;
                    //this.pcInsurance.Image = Utility.byteArrayToImage(oDetail.InsuranceCardImage);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagefront);
                    try
                    {
                        //Process currentProcess1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        pcInsurance.Image= returnImage;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            ms.Flush();
                            ms.SetLength(0);
                            ms.Close();
                            ms.Dispose();
                            ms = null;
                            //GC.Collect();

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }

                    }
```

2nd Method :
where ***pcinsurance*** is my PictureBox

```
byte[] byteArray = oDetail.InsuranceCardImage;
var imageStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(imageStream);
pcInsurance.Image = image;
```

Still cant fix this issue ,
Kindly provide your solutions so that i will carry on my work
Thank You.

Comment: do you mean the second method also gives the error? do you dispose memorystream in the second method ?

Comment: Yes Second Method also gives the error .No I Didn`t Dispose the Memory Stream on the Second Method

Comment: Try to move MemoryStream from method to class field, I have a guess that GC dispose it on time of rendering...

Comment: I already tried it  . Thats why I comment this GC line .

Comment: I mean in second method, first method will not work, because you can't dispose stream that are being used by some bitmap... it is clear why first method doesn't work... did you try to use second method and move stream outside as a field?

Comment: What database did you use ?

Comment: but i disposed in the first method . u can see ms.Dispose(); ,yes i tried outside as a field but its doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `ms.Close();`,`ms.Dispose();` and  `ms = null;`?

You dispose this stream twice and afterwards set it to null.

Finally is performed always so `MemoryStream` is always disposed.

I suspect that all resources are released *before* they're used by GDI. I experienced similar problem some time ago.

According to MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

The solution was a creation a `Bitmap` object:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    this.pcInsurance.Image = bmp;
```

In fact I used `using` statement to simplify code, closing stream before final braces. Works exactly the same but is shorter and in my opinion more readable.

`Bitmap` and `picturebox.Image`objects must be disposed *before* setting another picture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: should i remove these lines ? 
ms.Close();,
ms.Dispose(); ,
ms = null;,
ms.Flush();,
ms.SetLength(0);?

Comment: as I stated before you are disposing stream too fast.

Comment: I removed finally block and added your two lines and also remove  Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: that's a move in good direction. I also recommend to look into MSDN to fully understand why you do so.

Comment: Okay its good for changing image into byte but can you tell me about converting Byte to Image which does not show GDI+ error .